# Angular: Elegant way to toggle visibility of two related inputs

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 related inputs in angular one is type number and the other is type text.

They both display the same value with the only difference being that the type text input displays the value of the type number input formatted for currency.

Only one of these is displayed at any given time. The behaviour I'd like is for the text input to be displayed initially and then on the click event the text input is hidden and the number input is shown. Similarly when the blur event happens on the number input the number input is hidden and the text input is shown.

The markup for this looks something like this:

```html
  <div>
    <input type="number" ng-model="aValue" ng-blur="hideMeAndShowInputBelow">
    <input type="text" ng-value="aValue | currency:'': '0'" ng-click="hideMeAndShowAndFocusInputAbove" readonly="readonly">
  </div>
```

I know I could add extra properties to make this work but being relatively new to Angular this feels like the sort of thing that there is probably an elegant solution for.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well, it does not solve your problem but have you tried https://github.com/aguirrel/ng-currency. it works pretty well!

Comment: I hadn't seen that. But I don't want to allow text input - even though it cleans up after itself.

Comment: Did you found a solution right now?

Comment: Yes. I'll post my solution in a little while - but based on the approaches in the answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions. I followed the same approach but because I had some additional requirements (I wanted the value to be focussed when switching to the edit mode so the user can edit immediately without having to click the input again) I ended up writing a directive. It's here:

[PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/I64NS4JkswFDqWnYgyCQ?p=preview)

But here is the markup.

```
<div class="mt-flight-input" ng-class="{'mt-dirty': value.newvalue != value.initial, 'mt-zero': value.newvalue == 0}">
  <input type="number" class="mt-input" placeholder="0" ng-show="value.isAuthoring" ng-model="value.newvalue" ng-blur="checkValue('blur', value)" ng-focus="checkValue('focus', value)">
  <input type="text" class="mt-input" placeholder="0" ng-show="!value.isAuthoring" ng-value="value.newvalue | currency:'': '0'| comma2dots" ng-click="showEditor($event, value)" ng-focus="showEditor($event, value)" readonly="readonly">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a variable in `ng-blur`/`ng-click` and hide/show the inputs depending on the variable value.

```
<div>
  <input type="number" ng-model="aValue" ng-show="showNumber" ng-blur="showNumber = false">
  <input type="text" ng-value="aValue | currency:'': '0'" ng-show="!showNumber" ng-click="showNumber = true" readonly="readonly">
</div>
```

Check the plunker here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/yMFiXWuUF1R9BPGr2usT?p=preview

Alternatively, if this is a component you're going to use multiple times around your app, you could create a custom directive that achieves the same functionality, and thus avoid a lot of code duplication etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try out something like this

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <button class="btn btn-success" type="text" ng-model="firstName" ng-show="display" ng-click="display=!display"> BUTTON 1</button>
      <br />
      <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="display=!display" ng-model="lastName" ng-show="!display"> BUTTON 2
    </button>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/82x8vvgHAKY16fTGmiyN?p=preview)